# Write a function that returns the average of all of the items in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

The following is my code, so far I keep receiving `NaN`.

```
function yo() {
  var numbers = new Array([4, 5, 7, 2]);
  var total = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total += numbers[i];
  }

  var avg = total / numbers.length;
  console.log(avg);
  alert(avg);

  return avg;
}

yo();
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Hint, `new Array([4, 5, 7, 2]);` is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `[]` at call to `new Array()` which returns an array using parameters passed. `new Array([])` returns an array within an array.

```
var numbers = new Array(4, 5, 7, 2);
```

```js
function yo() {

  var numbers = new Array(4, 5, 7, 2);
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total += numbers[i];
  }
  var avg = total / numbers.length;
  console.log(avg);
  alert(avg);

  return avg;
}
yo();
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line from

`var numbers = new Array([4, 5, 7, 2]);` to `var numbers = [4, 5, 7, 2];`

Answer (score 0):

Here your problem is that you are creating an array within an array

try console.log(numbers)

If you want to use the new Array syntax you don't need [] inside of it in order to return a proper 1 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You've initialized `numbers` as an Array of an Array of 3 elements.

In your code, `numbers` is `[[4, 5, 7, 2]]`, when you're probably expecting it to be `numbers = [4, 5, 7, 2]`.

You could change the `numbers` assignment to read:

```
var numbers = new Array(4, 5, 7, 2); // remove the brackets
// or
var numbers = [4, 5, 7, 2];
```